# Have a responsive button

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, post

I'm new in RoR, and i need some advices

To explain the general concept, a user can create recipe(post) which are private. And once that, the user can publish the post adding a price and a quantity. And a wall is referencing all the last published post.

Now, I'm intending to make a button to publish my private posts into a public wall. And I'm not sure of the way to do that.
[Pushing button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiBXj.png)

Idealy, I would be able to edit a price and a number for each new publishing

I currently build post, ingredients, comments, user and user profile.

Should generate a scaffold for this action or add news variables to my post ?

if you want to see my code =

post_controller :

```html
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :owned_post, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
end  


  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show

  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = current_user.posts.build
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:user_id, :title, :description, :image, ingredients_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy])
    end

    def owned_post  
  unless current_user == @post.user
    flash[:alert] = "That post doesn't belong to you!"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end  

end
```

profiles/show :

```html
  <div class="row profile-header">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="img-circle">
        <%= profile_avatar_select(@user) %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="user-name-and-follow">
        <h3 class="profile-user-name">
          <%= @user.pseudo %>
        </h3>
        <span>
          <% if @user == current_user %>
            <%= link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_profile_path(@user.pseudo) %>
              
            
          <% end %>
        </span>
      </div>
      <p class="profile-bio">
        <%= @user.bio %>
      </p>
      <div class="user-statistics">
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p>
          <%= pluralize @user.posts.count, 'post' %>
        </p>
<div>
<%-@posts.each do |post| %>

<div class="toca">
   <%= render 'posts/post2', post: post %>
   <% end %>
</div>
  </div>
```

and the post2 :

```html
<div class="row">
<%-@posts.each do |post|%>

<div class="post">
  <div class="form-group text-center">
    <h3> <%=post.title%></h3>
  </div>

  
 <p> Posted by : <%= link_to post.user.pseudo, profile_path(post.user.pseudo) %>,  <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago </p>
  <div class="image text-center">
    <div class="image-border">
     <%= link_to (image_tag post.image.url(:medium), class: 'img-responsive'), post_path(post)%>
    </div>
  </div>

  
 
    
 

  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <%= link_to '-  Pusher  - ', post, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
  
  
  </div>
  <% end %>
 </div>
 </div>
```

So if you have any propositions to suggest me the best way for you

Comment: If you clarify your question you'll have a better chance of getting an answer.  What do you mean by responsive button?

Comment: Yes, sorry i just mean a button,
I wanted to know what you advice me for make a action publish a post into a public wall, because a tried a lot of way to do that.

Comment: The photo is the show of my profile controller, and the button should change automatically the private:boolean and allow me to edit a price and a quantity my post

Comment: Please read "[WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)" and "[How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)". They're very informative and will help you understand how to ask on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= link_to '-  Pusher  - ', post, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

You can create a new method to update the attribute:

```
<%= link_to '-  Pusher  - ', post, class: 'btn btn-primary', controller: "post", action: :go_public %>
```

Then you can write code to go public:

```
def go_public(params)
  @post = Post.find(id)
  @post.update_attributes(public_boolean: true)
end
```

Comment: Exactly that i'm looking for, it's working perfect ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

RESTfully, you should have a `POST` action on `/wall/posts` that:

- Takes the id, price, and photo of a `Post`
- Finds the `Post` by ID
- Updates the price/photo parameters
- Sets a "public" flag to true

You should also have a `DELETE` action at `/wall/posts/:id` that:

- Finds the `Post` by ID
- Sets the "public" flag to false

Which would remove the `Post` from the wall, but not delete the `Post` itself.

You can change the URL to `/wall` or something prettier, but I purposely made it more resource-oriented just so you can see what's going on.

Now, the button itself (which, I presume based on the fact you want more information means you'll need a form to go along with it), will need to POST to `/wall/posts`.

So, all that said, I think that's the "right" way to go.  But to answer the question I think you are leading to, you can also add a separate method to your current controller, by updating `routes.rb`:

```
resources :posts do
  post :publish, on: :member
end
```

Which will yield a route like `/posts/1/publish` or `publish_post_path(@post)` as a helper method.  Then, you can make a function in your posts_controller called `publish` to handle that route.  Now, that may seem more logical in a functional sense, but it breaks out of REST. But, it can be done.  I think the above is a little more logical, but that's just my thinking.

As an exercise, you can also create an 'unpublish' route the very same way, which you can use to remove wall posts as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a flag for posts, like `is_public` and make it false by default when creating a new one, which means post is private.

When a user wants to make a post public they need to click on button:

```
<%= link_to "-  Pusher  - ", post_path(post, is_public: true), method: :put, class: "btn btn-success" %>
```

This way, you created a link as a bootstrap button which is referenced to:

> /posts/:id, method: :put.

In your `posts_controller` you can catch this via `params[:is_public]` and to successfully update your post.

This way you are staying RESTfull without any additional function in your controller.